# Question about the first part of the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Tags: calculus

We know if $g$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and $F(x) = \int_a^x g(t) dt $, then
$$F'(x) = g(x) $$

But, how about if we have

$$ F(x) = \int_a^{h(x)} g(t) dt $$

What should $F'(x)$ be?? can we still apply fundamental theorem of calculus? thanks.

Comment: Why not? 

$$F'(x)=g(h(x))h'(x)$$

Comment: Chain rule ...${}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you have :
$$\int_a^{h(x)}g(t)dt = G(h(x)) - G(a)$$
where $G'(x) = g(x)$. Hence :
$$[G(h(x))]' = h'(x)G'(h(x)) = h'(x)g(h(x))$$
by the chain rule.

Comment: I think your chain computation is wrong.

Comment: @MathcanbeFun: indeed thanks. I forgot to write $h$ again...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need also the chain rule. Obviously, $h$ must be differentiable.

$$F'(x)=h'(x)g(h(x))$$